# ios - how to add view dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

i am new to ios develepoment

i have created a function name list which is called after a button is clicked it should load a view dynamically this is my code

```
-(IBAction)list:(id)sender{

UIView *listView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,786)];

[self.view addSubview:listView];
}
```

but it does not create any view but it calls this function
can anyone help me

Thanks.
Arun

Comment: set a background color for the view and check it ...

Comment: are you sure that this function is calling, mean you have proper IBAction connection

Comment: By default, a view will use clear color for its background, that's why you don't see it.

Comment: yes the color of the view changed

Comment: @Arun so ur view is added rite ?

Comment: so can i add a label or button in it like this what to do if i want to disappear the previous view.
Thanks for your help

Comment: yes your can add label, button or whatever you want to add on  your listView. just check my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any problem with your code, It will work fine.
You just check two thing

1. Make some background color in your view

   [`listView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];`
2. You have proper `IBAction` connection on your button

If you getting `redColor` on your `View` mean `listView` is adding over your view.

**EDIT**

If your want to add `UILabel` and `UIButton` in your view then

```
[listView addSubview:yourLabel];
[listView addSubview:yourButton];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
listView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

If you don't see anything on `self.view`, check by

```
for(UIView *aView in self.view.subviews){
     NSLog("%@\n",aView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make property of listView in .h

```
-(IBAction)list:(id)sender{
   self. listView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,786)];
   [self. listView setHidden:NO];
   [self. listView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
   [self.view addSubview:self.listView];
}
```

Try out this.

Answer (score 0):

[self. listView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
 your view display with green color..if it is not display check out the connection to the -(IBAction) method...